# Text input onchange event

Tags: javascript, entities

I'm working on a custom field that will store a string.  The text will have a custom formatter applied to it that will manipulate the structure of the string (adding dashes in the right places).  I have a javascript that will apply those changes in the field's input textbox when creating a new content type with the custom field, but I can't figure out how to fire the javascript when the user enters the text.  Can it be done and if so can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: show us your code

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use Drupal behaviors which is a wrapper of sorts for JQuery. With JQuery you can make it so that everytime your textfield gets edited your Javascript code gets executed. Behaviors/JQuery is a big subject and will take time if you're not familiar. You can start here

[The Drupal JavaScript API](http://drupal.org/node/304258)

[JQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

1.With the help of onblur() function,you can trigger the written js.
2.onblur() function helps you in calling a js once the text is entered in the input field and the user press ENTER after entering the text.